# How to activate programs on windows from Linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, windows-xp, remote-access, winexe

First I will explain my target

Target - execute programs or scripts on my windows machine from my Linux machine

I find the winexe tool – this tool perform remotely executes commands on remote windows machine from my Linux – very nice,

real example about winexe tool , and how it works:

The following example syntax should open the IE on my windows machine from my Linux (very nice )

```
  ./winexe -U login%password -W WORKGROUP //remore_machine_ip "cmd /k    cscript C:/open-explorer.vbs"
```

**open-explorer.vbs** script looks like that:

```
 Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
 WshShell.Run "iexplore http://www.google.com", 9
```

So now I will explain the problem .....
Regarding the winexe syntax I see that winexe actually execute the open-explorer.vbs script but !

IE not really  popup/opened? On my windows???

But when I run/exe the **open-explorer.vbs** script on my windows the IE (google) explorer opened successfully

So why IE opened from windows machines and not by the winexe tool?
I guess because the winexe can’t see windows ENV ? Or maybe something else?

Please advice – how to open the IE on my windows machine by winexe tool

what need to add/change/replace in my winexe syntax to open the IE on WIN ?

**WINEXE tool syntax**

```
       ./winexe -U login%password -W WORKGROUP //remore_machine_ip "cmd /k    cscript C:/open-explorer.vbs"


 login - WIN login
 password  - WIN password
 remore_machine_ip - WIN ip address
```

winexe site - http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Winexe

Comment: Have you tried `--interactive=1` and `--system` as parameters to `winexe`?

Comment: yes good idea ( I will try it - ) - please write answer for my question and I will vote for you...

Comment: hey guys, can you provide the full line, because using --interactive=1 and --system gives me just like I wrote --help or something: my line: winexe --system -U "work/user%pw043" --interactive=1  //server.something --system "C:\Utility\prog.exe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of winexe](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Winexe#Common_options):

```
--interactive=0|1
  Desktop interaction: 0 - disallow, 1 - allow. 
  If you allow use also --system switch (Win > requirement). 
  Vista do not support this option.
```

So `--interactive=1 --system` should do the trick.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this and provide me with an example, why this line of mine doesn't work it just activates --help section of winexe sort of: winexe --system -U "work/user%pw043" --interactive=1 //server.something --system "C:\Utility\prog.exe"