# Winexe command gives returns irrelevant info and doesn't execute

Tags: user-interface, remote-access, windows-server, psexec, winexe

Hey guys I am trying to use winexe and execute interactive gui programs from my linux machine to my windows and this syntax is just giving me the same thing like I write

```
winexe --help
```

Why is that so? I read that on this post: [How to activate programs on windows from Linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633077/how-to-activate-programs-on-windows-from-linux-machine)

**If I use --system and --interactive=1 in my command, I will be able to run gui programs on my target machine**

```
winexe --system -U "work/user%pw043" --interactive=1 //server.company.co --system "C:\Utility\prog.exe"
```

So, what is the proper syntax to making this work? I googled all over internet and the resources on this topic are really scarce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to run executables using combination of winexe and psexec64

```
winexe -U DOMAIN/user%password //SERVER.company.co "psexec64 -u DOMAIN\user -p password -accepteula -nobanner -h -i 2 C:\windows\notepad.exe
```